# Change DB Path - Mongodb sharded cluster

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

I've set up a mongodb sharded cluster on Ubuntu 18.04 with mongodb version 4.2.8.
I followed mongodb official documentation on the following link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

My question is, after configuring everything (Config servers, Shards and mongoS), how can I change the location for the storage of my data on shards. Right now I did it something like this

```
--dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

I want to change it from above location to new location. How can I do this?

Comment: Change that parameter?

Comment: See these two topics for guidance. (1) [Migrate a Sharded Cluster to Different Hardware](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/) , see the section on Migrate the Shards _and_ (2) [Re-start a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/restart-sharded-cluster/). You can update your post with details like - if you have sharded any database / collection and if so, there is any data in the database / collection.